# Remove "choose from gallary" option in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, html, uiimagepickercontroller

i am working on project which provides functionality of capturing image from any phone and upload it to websites server.

but i am facing problem while using iphone.

it shows "Choose from gallary" option as well when user clicks on Snap it button.

here is image:

[image]

Is it possible to disable this option ? how to disable this option from iphone whenever this website is used?

i want to remove option "Choose existing".

Comment: restricts photos but i  want to restrict user. user must not be able to upload from galary("Choose existing").

Comment: why are you add this "Choose Existing" option in ActionSheet if you don't want? @chetanpatel :)

Comment: i think this is a built in option in iphone.

Comment: i am working on browser, not an application. when user clicks on "snap" button, it should open camera directly.

Comment: reference: http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera  use this link in your phone

Comment: @chetanpatel if my answer helps you please make it as a accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this Code:**

```
        UIImagePickerController *imagePickController=[[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
        //You can use isSourceTypeAvailable to check

        if ([UIImagePickerController    isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            imagePickController.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            imagePickController.showsCameraControls=YES;
            //  self.usingPopover = NO;
        }
        else if ([UIImagePickerController  isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {//Check PhotoLibrary  available or not
            imagePickController.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            imagePickController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        }
        else if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]) //Check front Camera available or not
            imagePickController.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        //else //!!!!!!!!!!!exception

        imagePickController.delegate=self;
        imagePickController.allowsEditing=NO;

        [self presentModalViewController:imagePickController animated:YES];
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but this is a website not an iphone application.

Comment: @chetanpatel this is used in iOS for iPhone.

Comment: its not for website it is used for iPhone. Read documentation of Apple first so that you will get idea of it. k

Comment: @chetanpatel it helps you or not...

Comment: but i have iPhone on that i have check it. and it run perfectly. so what is your issue.

Comment: use this link in my iphone 4s: http://davidwalsh.name/browser-camera                   not working in my iphone 4s

Comment: @chetanpatel why are you using this link..

Comment: i am following this example.